# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized (Snom D375)

Tags: c#, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I try to control my snom phone (D375) remotely with a C# Programm. This is the code for the remote dialing:

```
     string httpCallCommand = string.Format(
        HTTP_SNOM_CALL_COMMAND,
        Credentials.Instance.PhoneUri.ToString(),
        CALL_COMMAND,
        number,
        MY_NUMBER);

     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(httpCallCommand);
     request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Credentials.Instance.User, Credentials.Instance.Password);

     try
     {
        request.GetResponse();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        if (((WebException)e).Status == WebExceptionStatus.ConnectionClosed)
        {
           // Do nothing because it's normal for the Snom telephone to not answer on this request.
        }
        else if (e.Message.Contains("401"))
        {
           MessageHelper.MessageBoxService.ShowOnTop(
              MessageType.Error,
              MessageHelper.WrongSettingsMessage(true, true, true, ConnectionType.WRONG_CREDENTIALS));
           ClassLogger.Info(LogMessages.WrongCredentials, e.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
           MessageHelper.MessageBoxService.ShowOnTop(
              MessageType.Error,
              MessageHelper.WrongSettingsMessage(true, true, true, ConnectionType.NO_CONNECTION));
           ClassLogger.Info(LogMessages.NoConnection, e.ToString());
        }
     }
```

The call goes through, but I also get "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized" from the `request.GetResponse();`. The authentication scheme on the phone is set to Basic.
I can't figure out why I get the exception.
Here are some syntax information if needed http://wiki.snom.com/FAQ/Can_I_control_my_snom_phone_remotely

Comment: `HTTP Unauthorized 401` isn't an error in practice, rather a information that you are unauthorized to access the requested resource. for `Basic` authentication scheme, a header should be present in the request like `Authorization: Basic XXXXXxx..`

Comment: I also added `String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(
            Credentials.Instance.User + ":" + Credentials.Instance.Password));
         request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);` but I still get the 401 message

Comment: If you control the server, may be debug over there.

Comment: Thats the problem the server is on the phone and I have no chance to check the sourcecode. The only thing I have are the [syntax](http://wiki.snom.com/FAQ/Can_I_control_my_snom_phone_remotely) and a webinterface for the phone

Comment: I am experiencing this same issue, did you find a workaround / resolution ?